# Does DBContext in startup.cs of .netcore Represent the entire database in the ASP application?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

Is multiple `DbContext` allowed or it is supposed to be only one in an entire ASP application?

Code Snippet from my `Startup.cs`

```
public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddDbContext<PatientContext> (options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=MyDatabase.db"));
    services.AddDbContext<AdminAccountContext> (options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=MyDatabase.db"));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
```

Comment: You already seem to have two different contexts in your code. Is the code not working? Did you encounter problems?

Comment: @AlexPaven it compiled and ran well, wanted to know if there is a better way to think about it. Thats why I asked. Thanks for responding

Comment: You should rephrase your question.  You're asking if something is allowed, and your code demonstrates that it is allowed (it works).  Asking if there's a better way is an entirely different question.  As is, your question literally answers itself.

Comment: To answer the question found in the title, it can.  But in your example code, you clearly have the database split into multiple contexts, so again, your question answers itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly, it's allowed.  If they are pointing at two different databases, it's even necessary.  But even if not, it can be a useful way of differentiating the dependencies when they are consumed.